# Find a curve from a family passing through 3 points

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

A family of curves, depending on parameters (A,B,C) has equation

$y(t)=A^{B/(B-1)}(A-(1-B)∗C∗t)^{1/(1-B)}$

I am looking for a curve of that family that passes through 3 known points. 
It looks like a non-linear system to solve.

If the 3 known points are M1(t1,y1=y(t1)), M2(t2,y2=y(t2)) and M3(t3,y3=y(t3)).

The system looks like

$y(t1)=A^{B/(B-1)}(A-(1-B)∗C∗t1)^{1/(1-B)}$

$y(t2)=A^{B/(B-1)}(A-(1-B)∗C∗t2)^{1/(1-B)}$

$y(t3)=A^{B/(B-1)}(A-(1-B)∗C∗t3)^{1/(1-B)}$

How can we solve it for A,B,C ? How many solutions exist ?

This question is closed to a [previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602571/solving-system-to-find-a-curve-passing-through-3-points) I asked, but the equation of family is different.

Comment: Are $b$ and $B$ the same parameter?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for pointing it. I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprizingly or not, this model is exactly the same as the previous one with slight changes of notations.

In $$y=a^{\frac{b}{b-1}} (a-(1-b) c x)^{\frac{1}{1-b}}$$ make $$a=\alpha \qquad c =\alpha \gamma \qquad b=1+\beta$$ and get $$y=\alpha  (1+\beta  \gamma  x)^{-1/\beta }$$ So, the previous method works : just compute as before parameters $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ and, at solution, go back to $a,b,c$ from the above definitions.